# Decimal input, choice html-ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to obtain something like this:

[image]

How can I have a select with choice of two different values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build yourself an input like that using html, css and js. There's no native select box that you can use.

Comment: have you a little example?

Comment: It's actually going to be long a bit complex to do it. MAybe you could go with just 2 drop downs instead.